# A question about the continuity from above property of measure

Tags: real-analysis

In my text book, the "continuity from above" of a measure is stated as the following.

> $μ(A_k )→μ(A)$ if $μ(A_k )<+∞$ for some $k$ and $A_k↘A$, then

The following is the proof provided by the text book.

> Without loss of generality, we assume $μ(A_1 )<+∞$. Then $μ(A_k )<+∞$ for all $k$.
>
> $A_1=A+(A_1-A_2 )+(A_2-A_3 )+⋯$ where $A,A_1-A_2,A_2-A_3,…$ are disjoint. It is clear that $A_1-A_2,A_2-A_3,…$ are disjoint. $A$ and any of $A_1-A_2,A_2-A_3,…$ are disjoint because $A⊆A_k  ∀k$, thus $x∈A⇒x∉A_k-A_{k+1}$ since $x$ is both a member of $A_k$ and $A_{k+1}$.
>
> Now $μ(A_1 )=μ(A)+μ(A_1-A_2 )+μ(A_2-A_3 )+μ(A_3-A_4 )+⋯=μ(A)+μ(A_1 )-μ(A_2)+μ(A_2 )-μ(A_3)+μ(A_3 )-μ(A_4)+⋯$
>
> The terms in the middle can cancel out, therefore $μ(A_1 )=μ(A)+μ(A_1 )-\lim_{k→∞}⁡μ(A_k)$, thus $μ(A)=\lim_{k→∞}⁡μ(A_k)$.

**The text book then explains that $μ(A_k )<+∞$ is necessary**, for example, let $A_k$ be the complement of the ball centered at 0 with radius $k = 1,2,3,...$, then every ball has Lebesgue measure $+\infty$ and hence $\lim_{k→∞}⁡μ(A_k)=+\infty$, but $A_k↘\emptyset$ and the measure of an empty set is zero.

**I have a problem with the proof**. It seems perfectly OK to me even if every $μ(A_k )=+∞$. I am not sure what is wrong with the proof when $μ(A_k )=+∞$ for all $k$.

I am not sure but my thinking is that things like $-\mu(A_2)+\mu(A_2)$ still seems to be $0$ even if $μ(A_2 )=+∞$ so the terms in the middle still cancel out?

And then we can still arrive at $μ(A_1 )=μ(A)+μ(A_1 )-\lim_{k→∞}⁡μ(A_k)$?

And then the left-hand side $\mu(A_1)$ can still cancel the right-hand side $\mu(A_1)$?

Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\mu(A_k) =  \infty$ you cannot cancel out the terms in the middle since $\infty - \infty$ makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I still don't understand. Every two terms in the middle are the  measures of the same set although they are infinite. $-\mu(A_k)+\mu(A_k)$ cannot cancel when $\mu(A_k)$ is $\infty$?

Comment: I understand your concern. See many operations concerning the infinite are simply not legal for instance $1-1 + 1 - 1+1 - 1 \ldots = ???$  Strange thongs happen and to keep coherence we agree that such strange operations are not legal. Once you have the counterexample of the sets $A_k = [k,\infty)$ you should "see" that something is going bad in the argument the author  just gave above and you wrote in the Original Post.  See also this  $a_n = n+1$ $b_n = n$ $a_n \to \infty$ $b_n \to \infty $ $a_n - b_n \to ???$

Comment: No, $-\mu(A_k)+\mu(A_k)$ does not equal $0$ when $\mu(A_k)=\infty$. The expression $\infty-\infty$ is _undefined_.